# Android WebRTC - How to fix PeerConnection.createOffer error "CreateOffer called with invalid media streams"?

Tags: android, webrtc

Following [this tutorial](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/) I have successfully created a GLSurfaceView that displays my local video in my Android app. I am using Pristine's gradle build scripts to use native code for webrtc. The web app works as expected in Chrome.

I have established a connection to my nodejs server via web sockets to join a pre-existing conversation. Kurento is being used to deal with rooms. I believe I need to create an SDP Offer to begin sending and receiving videos between peers at this point. (To begin I simply want the video from the Android device to appear on the web interface.)

However if I create a PeerConnection and add my local media stream (created with PeerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream) and then call createOffer() it fails.

The SDPObserver that listens to my connection gets its onCreateFailure called with the message "CreateOffer called with invalid media streams."

Looking at the C code it appears that the streams do not have unique IDs (despite the fact I have only created one stream).

I've been trying to figure this out for a day now and don't seem to be making any progress. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are setting the track and media Ids I am assuming and making sure that they are unique to your project right?

Comment: I'll have to go double-check but I believe the audio and video counted as separate streams so I needed unique ids between those. My solution was "<userid>_audio" and "<userid>_video" which (if I recall) solved the issue.

Comment: I know that the TRACKS are considered separate and need unique Ids but I have had audio and video in the same mediastream before(which also has a unique id).